# Faster mean calculation (openCV, C++)

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, mean

I am calculating the mean value of multiple squared regions inside an image in C++. Therefore I am shifting a squared region over the image and calculating the mean calculation with the openCV "mean" function, but replaced it with a std. mean calculation (see below), which was unexpectedly faster. Nevertheless it takes ~8ms on an Android device, since the mean calculation is called about 400 times (each mean calculation takes ~0.025ms)

```
uchar rectSize = 10;
Rect roi(0,0,rectSize, rectSize);
int pxNumber = rectSize * rectSize;
uchar value;

//Shifting the region to the bottom
for(uchar y=0; y<NumberOfRectangles_Y; y++)
{
    p = outBitMat.ptr<uchar>(y);
    roi.x = rectSize;

    //Shifting the region to the right
    for(uchar x=0; x<NumberOfRectangles_X; x++, ++p)
    {
        meanCalc(normalized(roi),rectSize, pxNumber, value);
        roi.x += rectSize;
    }

    roi.y += rectSize;
}


 void meanCalc(const cv::Mat& normalized, uchar& rectSize, int& pxNumber, uchar& value)
{
   for(uchar y=0; y < rectSize; y++)
   {
      p = normalized.ptr<uchar>(y);

      for(uchar x=0; x < rectSize; x++, ++p)
      {
        sum += *p;
      }
   }
   value =  sum / (float)pxNumber;
}
```

Is there a way to speed this mean calculation of each rectangular window inside the image up? Can I do some kind of pre-pixel ordering to only calculate the mean once and being faster?

Thanks in advance

*Update*

Based on the answer of User 6502 and the use of a sum table I resulted in the following:

```
Mat tab;
integral(image,tab);
int* input = (int*)(tab.data);
value = (input[yStart*tabWidth + xStart] + input[(yStart+rectSize)*tabWidth + xStart+rectSize]
                   - input[yStart*tabWidth + xStart+rectSize] - input[(yStart+rectSize)*tabWidth + xStart]) / (double)pxNumber;
```

Whereby this function needs almost the same times. Can it be that the sum table is only useful, when calculating a lot of overlapping regions. Because in my case, I only touch each pixel for calculation only once.

Comment: You should take a look at [summed area tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table)

Comment: Since you tagged OpenCV, you can use [cv::integral](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral)

Answer (score 6):

You can compute the mean over any rectangle in constant time (independently of the rectangle size) by pre-computing a "[summed area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table)".

You need to compute a table where the element `(i, j)` is the sum of all original data in the rectangle from `(0, 0)` to `(i, j)` and this can be done in a single pass over the data.

Once you have the table the sum of values between `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` can be computed in constant time with:

```
tab(x0, y0) + tab(x1, y1) - tab(x0, y1) - tab(x1, y0)
```

To understand how the algorithm works it's easier to think first to the one-dimensional case: to compute in constant time the sum of values from `v[x0]` to `v[x1]` you can pre-compute a table with

```
st[0] = v[0];
for (int i=1; i<n; i++) st[i] = st[i-1] + v[i];
```

and then you can take the difference `st[x1] - st[x0]` to know the sum of any interval of the original data.

The algorithm can indeed be easily extended to `n` dimensions.

Moreover it may be not evident at a first sight but the precomputation of the summed area table can be implemented for a multi-core architecture to take advantage of parallel execution.

For 2d a simple decomposition is to consider that computing the 2d sum table is the same as computing a 1d sum table on each row and then computing an 1d sum table for each column on the result.

Comment: This is done in OpenCV by [cv::integral](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral)

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I am just implementing and measuring runtime if there is an performance improvement. I will post my results afterwards.

Comment: Also called integral images. I think this is also used in the Viola-Jones face detection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optimized version your function menCalc from [Simd Library](http://simd.sourceforge.net/):

```
SIMD_API void SimdValueSum(const uint8_t * src, size_t stride, 
    size_t width, size_t height, uint64_t * sum);
```

It is much faster because uses different SIMD like SSE, AVX and so on.